# The order of an element to the power of $k$ is less or equal to the order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

> If $G$ is a group, $a \in G$, and $k$ is a positive number, proof that $o(a^k) \le o(a)$.

First of all, I'm still confused on what $o(a^k)$ means.

I knew that if $\gcd(k, o(a))=1$ then $o(a^k)=o(a)$ is true by using this theorem $o(a^k)= \frac {n}{\gcd(n,k)}$, for $o(a)=n$.

So can I use the same theorem for $o(a^k) \le o(a)$?

If I can then does this simply can be proven with substituting $o(a^k)=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$ into $o(a^k) \le o(a)$ then I can have :

$$\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)} \le n$$
$$\frac{1}{\gcd(n,k)}\le 1$$ for
$$\gcd(n,k) \in \Bbb N$$

Comment: The theorem is overkill: simply note $\langle a^k\rangle\subseteq \langle a\rangle,\,$ or use $\,a^n=1\Rightarrow (a^k)^n = 1\ \ $

Comment: But, yes, it does follow immediately from the theorem, which implies more strongly that  $\,o(a^k)\mid o(a).\,$ This divisibility also follows by Lagrange, since the above subset inclusion is a subgroup inclusion.

Comment: I think I get it now with the $\langle a^k \rangle$ is a subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$. I didn't think that $\langle a^k \rangle$ is a subgroup. Thank you very much.

Comment: But you only need to use  $\,o(c) = |\langle c\rangle|,\,$ i.e. the order of $c$ is the size of the subgroup it generates.